# Toggle on and off fill for checklist

Tags: java, processing, fill, dropdownchecklist

I made a checklist in processing that fills in a bubble every time i click it, however I am struggling to figure out how to be able to click the ellipse and it fills in, and then when i click it again, it will return back to the way it was, which is with a white fill. How do I make it so that I can toggle between a black fill and a white fill for my checklist? I have attempted to make a check boolean that will become true whenever It is clicked, and then if it is true, then it should fill the ellipses with white, however I don't know why that is not happening.

```
class Button {
// Other optional attributes could be r, g, and b values for examples
int xLoc;
int yLoc;
int wide;
int tall;
int fill;
boolean checked;

Button(int x, int y, int w, int h, int f) {
xLoc = x;
yLoc = y;
wide = w;
tall = h;
fill = f;
}

void display() {
//fill with blue green and create the rect 
fill(fill);
if (mousePressed) {
  if (isClicked() == true) {
    fill = 0;
  }
  else if(isClicked() == true){
   fill = 255; 
  }
 }
 ellipse(xLoc, yLoc, wide, tall);
 }

 // returns true if the mouse is over the button and false otherwise
 boolean isClicked() {
 if (mouseX > xLoc - 10 && mouseX < xLoc + wide/2) {
  if (mouseY > yLoc - 10 && mouseY < yLoc + tall/2) {
    return true;
       }
     }
   return false;
  }

  boolean isChecked() {
  if (fill == 0) {
  return true;
  } 
  else {
     return false;
      }
    } 
  }
```

main code:

```
Button button1 = new Button(50, 50, 20, 20, 255);
Button button2 = new Button(50, 75, 20, 20, 255);
Button button3 = new Button(50, 100, 20, 20, 255);
Button button4 = new Button(50, 125, 20, 20, 255);

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
background(50);
button1.display();
button2.display();
button3.display();
button4.display();
}
```

Comment: Like I asked in your other question, please post your code as a [mcve] with proper indentation and formatting. Also, please either edit or delete your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897582/creating-a-checklist-in-processing) which is not really answerable in its current form.

Comment: I tried to delete the previous question, but it would not let me. as for this question, I edited it

Comment: Sorry, but this still isn't an MCVE. This is just a class without any code that calls it.

Comment: umm? `if (isClicked() == true) {
    fill = 0;
  }
  else if(isClicked() == true){
   fill = 255; 
  }`